# What is the reason cause memory leak when I run a C# application to navigate website

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

Now I'm running C# application on windows 2008 R2.
I want to navigate some website in the new Form and catch some information from the webbrowser.

However, when I open Form and navigate website more times, the memory become more high.
I checked the memory use, and found out the reason is svchost use a lot of memory.

"svchost.exe, LOCAL SERVICE, 1816244K"

Also, I found out these dlls are running in this svchost.
"W32Time", "nsi", "netprofm", "FontCache", "EventSystem"

I have searched from google, but most of problem are about AutoUpgrade functions, not net problem.

How could I avoid increasing this memory in svchost?

Thanks

Sorry for poor English.

Answer (score 0):

These are window services and part of the operating system. They use memory. This isn't a memory-leak or anything to do with running a C# application.

Comment: Thanks for relpying. How could I avoid increasing memory in svchost?

Comment: Currently one of our primary servers has an svchost which includes the windows services you mentioned with a committed 1GB of memory. This server only has 4GB so I understand your frustration with the memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue when you use Web Browser control in C#, that could be the culprit

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893629

Following link is having some workarounds for this issue,

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/281541/memory-leak-in-system-windows-forms-webbrowser-object

Comment: Wouldn't this increase the memory usage of the Internet Explorer process, or application process hosting an IE instance/COM? And not windows services?

Comment: I know C# webbrowser will lead the memory leak in C# application. But why svchost hold much memory

Comment: Yes, I suspect that it is due to web browser control, not in Services.